# MVC 4: Why publishing web still reference to the development folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a very weird problem. I published the MVC 4 program to IIS into

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AlvinCMS`,

but when I ran the program from IIS (run the published one), somehow the code is still referencing the path to the development folder

(`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Alvin CMS\Alvin CMS`).

This is proved when I the system try to attach database with this connection string:

```
public static string CreateDefaultValueDBConnectionString()
{
    const string dataSource = ".\\SQLEXPRESS";
    const string initialCatalog = "AlvinCMS_Default";
    const string attachedFileName = "AlvinCMS_Default.mdf";

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
    sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = initialCatalog;
    sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
    sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    sqlBuilder.AttachDBFilename = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", "db", "backup", attachedFileName);

    return sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
}
```

The `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", "db", "backup", attachedFileName);` always targets the development folder `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Alvin CMS Project\Alvin CMS\Alvin CMS` not the published folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AlvinCMS`. Also I always get this error when try to access my view

> The virtual path '/DynamicForm/LoginPartial.cshtml/' maps to another application, which is not allowed

How can I stop the referencing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [`Server.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` ?

```
sqlBuilder.AttachDBFilename = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/db/backup"), attachedFileName);
```